# Python: Class Attributes Vs Getters and Setters?

Tags: python, class, oop, attr

It appears many times while working with Python classes it is quite possible to get the same functionality  with `getMyAttr()` and `setMyAtt()` methods instead of declaring the class attributes/variables such as `self.myVariable`

The more I work with OOP the more I tend to use class methods to get and set the attributes.
I wonder if a direction I am taking is right and if I am not going to be sorry 10K lines of code later. Please advice!

Comment: Why do you want to use getters/setters instead of just accessing the attributes directly?

Comment: You should be using a mixture of direct access and `@property`, as the situation requires.  They are syntactically interchangeable for a reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're thinking in the right direction but you should be looking at Python `properties` to do what you're doing:

```
 class Foo():
   def __init__(self, x):
     self.__x = x

   @property
   def x(self):
     return self.__x

   @x.setter
   def set_x(self, value):
     if(value < 0):
       self.__x = value
```

Wherein you can nest the "set" logic and the "get" logic (if you're changing how to present it.) This makes calling the value `x` from the class feel as if you're accessing attributes.

```
   foo = Foo(-4)
   foo.x
   >>> -4
   foo.x = 3
   foo.x
   >>> -4
   foo.x = -12
   foo.x
   >>> -12
```